# How to test domain project updates in Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule4

We are making updates to our Mule 4.3 domain project (runs on-prem in Prod environment). I would like to test initially with one or two of our projects/apps. However when Studio starts a test run (via Run Config), it always puts both the old and new domain versions in the runtime environment. This results in errors, because you cannot have two versions of the same domain at the same time.

Sample scenario:
Prior domain version - 1.0.0, new domain version - 1.1.0
Project-A POM specifies domain 1.1.0. All other project POM files still refer to version 1.0.

According to MuleSoft docs, "The [domain] version honors semantic versioning.
For example, if you set the version to 1.0.1, a domain with version 1.0.2 and later works, but a domain with version 1.0.0 does not."

Given the above statement, I would expect projects still referring to domain version 1.0.0 should work with 1.1.0, but I can't stop Studio from deploying 1.0.0 at start-up.

I've tried clearing the "domains" folder in the Studio runtime environment (C:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.3.0.ee_7.3.5.202212211223\mule\domains).

And I've cleared the domains-staging folder before running (C:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.3.0.ee_7.3.5.202212211223\mule\domains-staging). But both domain jar files get re-copied to this staging folder.

Turning off the project setting of "build automatically" did not change anything.

Tried to de-select the domain project from the runtime configuration before running, but that was not allowed by Studio.

How can I get Studio to deploy just the newer version of the domain (1.1.0)?

Comment: Please share snippets from your pom files showing the dependencies on application projects and the maven coordinates of the domain, a screenshot of the Run Configuration showing what projects are included in the execution and the domain configuration in the mule-artifact.json file of the applications.

Answer (score 0):

You should always let the automatic building process work as designed. Otherwise you will end with configurations that are not reproducible nor supported.

The documentation you quote refers to what happens in a standalone installation of Mule (ie outside Studio), where you manage what domain to deploy. Running inside Anypoint Studio is  different because Studio manages the deployments. It seems that you have too different versions of the same in the same workspace because some apps point to those different versions each.

You simply should point all the projects to the same version in Studio. Then you can deploy to a Mule server with the same or a newer semantic version. You should not deploy more than one version of a domain outside Studio anyway.